# Give more weight to documents having true in a boolean field

Tags: elasticsearch

(I use elasticsearch version 2.3.3)

I am doing a simple match query on a text field but now want to give more weight to documents having true in a given boolean field.

My current query is something like

```
{
  "query": {
      "match": {
          "title": "QUICK!"
      }
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "QUICK!"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "my_boolean_field": {
              "value": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```